# GCC in Mac vs GCC in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, gcc

I have read countless threads saying that gcc in in the Xcode directory blah blah.
I know its there. I can see it. But I dont want to have to know its there and I don't want to have to a) run XCode or b)edit my c programs from /Developer/usr/bin

I want to compile c and c++ programs in ANSI C from the command line and from ANY directory of my choosing similar to how I do it in linux.

ie:
gcc -o foo foo.c

then run ./foo

Is this possible in OSX lion or later?

Comment: In Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > install command line tools and then you can do it at whatever place.

Comment: I believe that you can find a command line compiler on OSX. You probably can find some `gcc` port, and you could at least find a `clang` (since Apple sponsors LLVM & Clang).

Comment: What is wrong with setting your PATH to where the compiler is, regardless of other solutions?

Comment: I have preferences but no Downloads. Using Xcode v 3.2.6 64 bit

Comment: How exactly to add to Path. I tried to edit .bashrc with this line:    export PATH=${PATH}:/Developer/usr/bin/

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode's options panel, select "Downloads", and click the "Components" tab. Select "install" next to "Command line tools". That will install them in the usual Unix locations.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 3.2.6. its already installed and I see no menu corresponding to Downloads in the preferences

Comment: For some reason, the Xcode developers like to play hide and seek with some features. Try the organizer, or look in the help for "command line tools".

Comment: None of these things you suggested are useful. Does nobody compile c programs from the terminal? Must I go back to linux. This seems strange.

Comment: I do it all the time. Sorry I can't help you.

Comment: You didn't mention at first that you were using Xcode 3.  That makes a big difference.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Depending on your shell, `export` or `setenv` (whether you are on bash or tcsh) the [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) variable with your path to gcc.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 3.2.6, you need to install the `UNIX Development` component using the `Xcode 3` installer package.  That will install the necessary links and header files in `/usr` and `/System/Library`.  See the `About Xcode 3.2.6` document included on the installer dmg or downloadable from the Apple Developer site (an unofficial copy is on the web [here](http://groups.ascd.org/resource/documents/122959-AboutXcode.pdf)).

In the most recent versions of Xcode 4, the `Command Line Tools` component is installed using `Xcode.app` itself as others have described.